# Traefik use Company CA

Tags: traefik

We would like to use Traefik with our CA certificate. Is there an option to use your CA certificate for automaticly signing the Autogenerated certificate generated for Domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rootCAs` option:

```
# Register Certificates in the RootCA.
#
# Optional
# Default: []
#
RootCAs = [ "/mycert.cert" ]
```

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/commons/#main-section

Comment: thanks, but i meant is that the Browser Certificate should be signed with the CA.
rootCAs is for the Connection to the backend or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it took me a while until I found a solution.

To apply whole chain you have to create a bundle and pass it as regular `CertFile`. Order matters, first goes your service cert and then intermediate cert.

```
cat ca.crt > bundle
cat intermediate.crt >> bundle
```

Config part:

```
[[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
CertFile = "bundle"
KeyFile = "tls.key"
```

Valid for Traefik 1.7